# Trying to join a query for salesforce on python

Tags: python, django, salesforce

I want to make a query from salesforce using an id

```
opportunity_id="0061g00000BRG00AAH"
query = "SELECT+FIELDS(ALL)+FROM+Opportunity+WHERE+ID+=+'"+opportunity_id+"'"
print(json.dumps(sf_api_call('/data/v51.0/query/', {"q": query})))
```

But I get this error:

```
b'[{"message":"\\nSELECT+FIELDS(ALL)+FROM+Opportunity+WHERE+ID+=+\'0061g00000BRG00AAH\'\\n     ^\\nERROR at Row:1:Column:6\\nunexpected token: \'+\'","errorCode":"MALFORMED_QUERY"}]'
```

Comment: What does `sf_api_call()` do? Your error suggests some issues with escaping and newlines, which are not present in the code shown.

Answer (score 0):

The error is for the first + in the query (after select). It looks like you're manually url encoding the query, and then something further down is also encoding it. remove the encoding from the query.

`query = "SELECT FIELDS(ALL) FROM Opportunity WHERE ID='"+opportunity_id+"'"`